# Info sources to improve safety on a Mac (OSX)

Tags: privacy, macos

I was thinking about buying some crypto currencies, but want to make sure that my computer is safe and secured before that.

Could anyone provide me with some links to some tutorials or best practices? The information should be easy to digest for a none-advanced user.

My current setup on my MacBook is:

- Bitdefender anti-virus
- OSX built-in firewall Little Snitch (checks to
  ingoing/outgoing connections)
- Oversight (to see if mic or camera is
  on)
- Lastpass Yubikey (for Lastpass usage and to enter the computer)
- Google/Lastpass Authenticator for 2FA to enter most valuable sites

Comment: unfortunately, your question is impossibly broad

Comment: Actually it is not broad at all. There are many sites that could fit the answer and the answer could consist of one url and a brief explanation such as: "www.privacytools.io is considered one of the top sites when it comes to securing ones computer. You could start there."

Asking for recommendations for all the questions above, THAT would be a broad question.

Comment: That would end up being a recommendation for a site, which would be off topic too.

Comment: How is that off-topic when the question asked was: "Could anyone provide me with some links to some tutorials or best practices?"

Comment: Because we are not a link dump. As a Q&A site, the answers could be here and not on other sites.

Comment: Ok, didn't know it was bad practice to ask for tutorials or articles on this forum.